2x2 linear system of congruences: necessary condition for existence and uniqueness.
Given the system
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
&ax+by\equiv e\pmod m\\
&cx+dy\equiv f\pmod m,
\end{aligned}\right.\tag{1}$$
define
$$\Delta=\det\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}=ad-bc.$$
Koshy's book presents the following result:

System $(1)$ has a unique solution if and only if $\gcd(\Delta,m)=1.$
Remark 1: "unique" means that if $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are two solutions, then $x_1\equiv x_2\pmod m$ and $y_1\equiv y_2\pmod m$.

His proof is as follows.

Suppose that $(x_0,y_0)$ is a solution. Then,
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
&ax_0+by_0\equiv e\pmod m\\
&cx_0+dy_0\equiv f\pmod m.
\end{aligned}\right.$$
Multiplying the first congruence by $d$, the second by $-b$ and adding, we conclude that
$$\Delta x_0\equiv ed-bf\pmod m.\tag{2}$$
Analogously, multiplying the first by $-c$, the second by $a$ and adding, we conclude that
$$\Delta y_0\equiv af-ce\pmod m.\tag{3}$$
Since $(2)$ has a unique solution $x_0$ iff $\gcd(\Delta,m)=1$ and $(3)$ has a unique solution $y_0$ iff $\gcd(\Delta,m)=1$, the desired result follows.

Remark 2: The argument uses the fact that $Ax\equiv B\pmod m$ has a unique solution iff $\gcd(A,m)=1$. Here, "unique" means that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two solutions, then $x_1\equiv x_2\pmod m$.

I understand that if the system does not have a unique solution, then $(2)$ or $(3)$ also does not have a unique solution. Therefore, in this case, $\gcd(\Delta,m)\neq 1$. By contrapositive, this shows that
$$\text{If $\gcd(\Delta,m)=1$, then the system has a unique solution.}$$
However, I did not understand how the converse follows from the presented argument. I'd like an explanation. Could someone give me details? Is it straightforward?
Remark 3: As I understand it, the proof would be complete provided that a solution $(x_0,y_0)$ of $(2)$-$(3)$ were also a solution of the system. It is possible to prove it without knowing that $\gcd(\Delta,m)=1$?

If $\gcd(\Delta,m)=1$, then $\Delta$ has an inverse $\Delta^{-1}$ mod $m$, so the solution is $x_0\equiv\Delta^{-1}(ed-bf)$

@J.W.Tanner Okay, but $\gcd(\Delta,m)=1$ is not a hypothesis for the converse.

If $\gcd(\Delta,m)=d$ and $\Delta x_0\equiv ed-bf$, then also $\Delta \left(x_0+\frac md\right)\equiv ed-bf\pmod m$ as well

@J.W.Tanner Is $x_0+\frac{m}{d}$ a solution of the system? If so, how to show it? If not, how does your comment imply that $\gcd(\Delta,m)=1$?

If $d>1$, then $x_0+\frac md$ is a distinct residue mod $m$ and yes it’s a solution

@J.W.Tanner Take the system $\left{\begin{aligned}&x+2y\equiv 2\pmod 6\&6x+4y\equiv 4 \pmod 6\end{aligned}\right.$. Then, $d=\gcd(\Delta,m)=2>1$. And $(x_0,y_0)=(0,1)$ is a solution. Are you saying that the distinct residue $x_0+\frac{m}{d}=3$ is a solution of the said system?

No, but $(x_0,y_0)=(0,4)$ is another solution

@J.W.Tanner Do you know how to prove that this other solution always exists? When does it exist for $x$ and when for $y$?
